# Remove line from bar chart (Python, Matplotlib and seaborn)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, python-3.9

Im have this code that gen a bar chart using seaborn and matplotlib.

```
fig = figure.Figure(figsize=figsize)
ax = fig.add_subplot()

g = sns.barplot(y=y, x=x, data=data, ax=ax, ci=False, orient='h', order=orderlist) 

g.set(xlabel=None, ylabel=None, xticks=[])

ax.set_yticklabels([], fontsize=9)

for x in g.containers:
    currency_labels = []

    for value in x.datavalues:
        currency_labels.append(
            format_decimal(value)
        )
    ax.bar_label(x, rotation=0, padding=5, fmt='%.0f', fontsize=9, labels=currency_labels)
        
sns.despine(ax=ax, left=True, bottom=True)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig(saveloc, dpi=2000)
```

that return this chart[image]
How can i remove these lines?

Comment: If only your code will be reproducible so we could copy paste and run it... Why didn't you create a code with fake hardcoded data, so it could be run?

Comment: Have a look at [`ax.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html)